# Why can't I use max() here?

Tags: beamer, pgfmath

When I make presentations (with beamer), I like to have a bar along the bottom showing progress through the presentation visually. The interesting bit of the code below is the division on the `node[fill=navfg,...]` line:

```
\usebeamercolor{palette primary}
\colorlet{navfg}{fg!80!white}
\colorlet{navbg}{fg!40!white}
\newcommand{\navradius}{0.25ex}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \tikz\draw[text height=2*\navradius,inner sep=0ex,rounded corners=\navradius]
        node[fill=navbg,minimum width=\textwidth-\navradius](back){} (back.west)
        node[fill=navfg,minimum width=(\insertframenumber-1)/(\inserttotalframenumber-1)*(\textwidth-\navradius),right]{}
        (back.south) node[below]{}
        ;
}
```

This works great, *except* during the first attempt to build a presentation using this snippet. During the first build, `\inserttotalframenumber` has the value `1`, so this makes a division by zero. The obvious fix is to use `max`:

```
node[fill=navfg,minimum width=(\insertframenumber-1)/max(1,\inserttotalframenumber-1)*(\textwidth-\navradius),right]{}
```

But this results in an error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \textwidth 
l.10 \begin{document}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Why do I get this error? What can I do to solve this problem correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If TikZ doesn't want to evaluate some expression correctly, you can often help it by surrounding the expression with braces. In your case,

```
node[fill=navfg,minimum width={(\insertframenumber-1)/max(1,inserttotalframenumber-1)*(\textwidth-\navradius)},right]{}
```

works correctly.

Comment: While that does make the errors disappear, it unfortunately also makes the navigation bar disappear.

Comment: It works for me. Maybe you could add a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Whoops, you're right, this works perfectly. My PDF viewer was just cutting off the bottom of each page during the test.